# Border disclosure in a grid

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, grid

I am currently looking for rationale to the following phenomenon:

1. `ASP.NET`

   ```
   <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4" style="font-size:16px;>
                  one column
                  </div>
                   <div class="col-md-4" style="font-size:16px;>
                  two column
                  </div>
                   <div class="col-md-4" style="font-size:16px;>
                  three column
                  </div>
          </div>
   <div>
   ```

Based on the above code, one could see each column separated by a vertical line.

2. `ASP.NET (Core) MVC`

After migrating to a `MVC` Framework, similar code was not displaying the vertical line used a a column separator.

As a way around, I've added a `CSS`, and while slightly amending the code to:

```
/* add column separator */
#divider .border {
border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}


<div class="container-fluid" id = "divider" >
          <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4 border" style="font-size:16px;>
                  one column
                  
                  <p> test</p>
                  </div>
                   <div class="col-md-4 border" style="font-size:16px;>
                  two column
                  <p> test2</p>
                  </div>
                   <div class="col-md-4 border" style="font-size:16px;>
                  three column
                  
                  </div>
           </div>
       </div>
```

Given the lack of improvements following online searches too, I am consequently curious to know any reason.

Thanks in advance.

Best.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are there vertical lines or not? And the `style="font-size:16px;` is missing a closing `"`

Comment: @VDWWD: Thanks for your feedback. There weren't initially, and I have posted own answer which is not perfect, as described. Curious to see if better alternatives exist.

Answer (score 0):

The below adjustment has eventually worked, although it's not perfect since the `height` of vertical lines is proportionate to the numbers of `rows` used in each `column`.

*N.B: I may thus use, as a way around, empty rows to ensure a certain `symmetry` while remaining opened to more robust suggestions.*

CSS

```
.border-right {
border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

ASP.NET (Core) MVC

```
<div class="container" >
          <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4 border-right" style="font-size:16px;>
                  one column
                  
                  <p> test</p>
                  </div>
                   <div class="col-md-4 border-right" style="font-size:16px;>
                  two column
                  <p> test2</p>
                  </div>
                   <div class="col-md-4" style="font-size:16px;>
                  three column
                  
          </div>
</div>
```